# ASP.NET MVC | Handle onunload event and pressing F5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I have onUnload event handler on my page. Also User can press F5 and reload page. When user pressed F5, The request from browser to server came fuster then request from onUnload. I need that request will come from onUnload then from F5.

onUnload handler

```
 $(window).unload(function () {
        var url = '<%= Url.Content("~/Controller/Action") %>/';
        var cancelButton = "resetStatus";

        $.post(url, { cancelButton: cancelButton}, function (data) {

        });
    });
```

Comment: Each time a page is refreshed, the existing page is first unloaded before the new page is got from the server. So it looks like using the onunload event is not the event you want/need. So you either need to change the design a bit or maybe use the onload event instead?

Comment: You can't do this. Ajax requests are sent asynchronously and you have no control of when they are sent or complete.

Comment: @Darin AJAX requests don't have to be sent asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

any solutions on this? This is happening in FF only. I have a popup and onunload needs to be called before f5 to clean session variables. but for ff, page load event is called before onunload.

Comment: as I remember we have found solution what not used browser events.